# C# Selenium XPath grabbing data from a table in a div

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

I am try to grab data from a table that has two columns.  The rows do not have a distinct identifier.  But I can search the first column for specifics to find out if I should grab the second column's data.  The table does not have an id, but the Div does.  I need to grab the dollar amounts seen in the screen shot below.  I would be very grateful for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following-sibling in xpath

```
//div[@id='subtotals-marketplace-table']//td[contains(text(),"Estimated tax")]/following-sibling::td[1]  
//div[@id='subtotals-marketplace-table']//td[contains(text(),"Total")]/following-sibling::td[1]
```

Comment: That was perfect.  Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest installing the firefox plugin firepath and get the xpath in this way

Comment: This is generally not a good idea because you will get very fragile XPaths.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using `By.xpath()` with [`preceding-sibling` axis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/preceding-sibling) as below :-

- To get `Estimated tax to be collected:`

  ```
  driver.FindElement(By.xpath(".//td[preceding-sibling::td[text() = 'Estimated tax to be collected:']]")).Text
  ```
- To get `Total:`

  ```
  driver.FindElement(By.xpath(".//td[preceding-sibling::td[text() = 'Total:']]")).Text
  ```